# How to model many to many with an "include all" option

Tags: database, database-design

lets say I have a number of custom report types. One report type can be associated with a number of file extension options (pdf, excel etc), each file extension for that specific custom report type has an number legal actions that can be used (say for report type A with pdf extension I may save, print and modify). However, the legal actions are mostly identical between extensions for a report, only in very few occasions do they differ. How would you model this relationship?

If I also would want the option that a custom report type should have all extension types and the same actions for each extension type, would you introduce some "magic value" like extension type * indicates that this report type should include all available extension types along with a base set of legal action, or would you simply populate the relationship manually with all extension types, legal actions etc and remember to update them when new extension types are introduced? This is not that common though.

Hope the question is somewhat clear:)

Comment: What is not clear is what your design goal is. If your goal is ultimately simple update of this data, then you need to design for the highest possible normal form. It doesn't look like your proposed design conforms to fifth normal form. If, however, your goal is simplicity at retrieval time, then you are better off making every set of legal actions keyed on file extension and report type, even if some of them are only functionally dependent on file extension.

Comment: This is for mostly reading, not modifying. Do I understand you correct if you're implying a table (reportType, extension, legalAction) ? How would it be done in 5th normal form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did struggle to follow the question, but I think you're saying:

a report type has one or more file extensions.

a file extension has one or more permissable action.

many file extensions share the same set of permissable actions.

If that's what you're saying, I would introduce the concept of "permissionSet", with a many-to-many relationship to individual permissions. A file extension has a many to many relationship with permission sets.

Comment: the file extension has one or more permissable actions for that report type. The actions for an extension may differ for another report type. OK, the permission set would make it possible for file extension to share permissions if they are identical, but also define a permissionset that is unique for itself?